# Large CSV manipulation

Tags: csv, command-line, fastercsv

I have a very large CSV file (over 100 million records) that I would like to delete several columns from.  I have tried the application CSVed (http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/#csvuni) but a file this size will not open.  Does anybody know what I would need to enter into the command line interface to delete specific columns?  I am using Windows 7.

Below are the columns I currently have.  I placed an "X" next to columns I would like to remove.

1. domainName
2. registrarName - **X**
3. contactEmail - **X**
4. whoisServer - **X**
5. nameServers - **X**
6. createdDate - **X**
7. updatedDate - **X**
8. expiresDate - **X**
9. standardRegCreatedDate - **X**
10. standardRegUpdatedDate - **X**
11. standardRegExpiresDate - **X**
12. status - **X**
13. Audit_auditUpdatedDate - **X**
14. registrant_email
15. registrant_name
16. registrant_organization
17. registrant_street1
18. registrant_street2
19. registrant_street3
20. registrant_street4
21. registrant_city
22. registrant_state
23. registrant_postalCode
24. registrant_country
25. registrant_fax - **X**
26. registrant_faxExt - **X**
27. registrant_telephone
28. registrant_telephoneExt
29. administrativeContact_email
30. administrativeContact_name
31. administrativeContact_organization
32. administrativeContact_street1
33. administrativeContact_street2
34. administrativeContact_street3
35. administrativeContact_street4
36. administrativeContact_city
37. administrativeContact_state
38. administrativeContact_postalCode
39. administrativeContact_country
40. administrativeContact_fax - **X**
41. administrativeContact_faxExt - **X**
42. administrativeContact_telephone
43. administrativeContact_telephoneExt

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Where are you working: Windows / UNIX / Mac? Post some sample input and desired output.

Comment: You can have a look at Perl's [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm) module to cook up a small script.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called cut, and can get it (for example) from gnuwin32, package coreutils.

And once you have it,

```
cut -d , -f 1,14-24,27-39,42-43 fileInput.csv > fileOutput.csv
```

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like there are many useful utilities in this package.  My only question is, now that I have downloaded them how do I use them?  If I go to the actual file for the utility under program files it launches the command prompt but then closes it immediately.  I have tried on both a Windows 7 machine and Windows XP machine.  Thanks.

Comment: It's a command line utility. Open command prompt, go to program directory and run `cut --help`. The command in answer needs also to be runned in command line or called from batch file.